# Remove all elements from a list after a particular value

Tags: python, list, indexing

Given a list `l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes, 'banana']`

How can I remove all items after `'pear'`

Comment: You could slice up to it - `l1[:2]`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

use list slice method

```
>>> l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
>>> target_ibdex = l1.index('pear')
>>> target_ibdex
1
>>> l1[:target_ibdex+1]
['apple', 'pear']
>>>
```

---

With exception handling when element is not present in the list.

```
>>> l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
>>> target_element = "mango"
>>> try:
...     target_index = l1.index(target_element) + 1
... except ValueError, e:
...     target_index = None
... 
>>> l1[:target_index]
['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
```

when element present in the list

```
>>> l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
>>> target_element = "pear"
>>> try:
...     target_index = l1.index(target_element) + 1
... except ValueError, e:
...     target_index = None
... 
>>> l1[:target_index]
['apple', 'pear']
```

Comment: You should check for the element being part of the list or try..catch ValueError

Comment: Instead of `target_index = len(l1)` - you could just use `target_index = None`

Answer (score 7):

You can build a custom generator function which will work on any iterable, not just lists - although for your example, `list.index`, exception handling and slicing is fine...

```
def takewhile_including(iterable, value):
    for it in iterable:
        yield it
        if it == value:
            return

l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
print('Until pear', list(takewhile_including(l1, 'pear')))
# Until pear ['apple', 'pear']
print('Until blah', list(takewhile_including(l1, 'blah')))
# Until blah ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
if "pear" in l1:
    l2 = l1[:l1.index("pear")+1]
    print l2
```

Output:

> > ['apple', 'pear']

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was interested how fast each solution is. Here is the code and estimations:

```
setup = """
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def dropwhile_v1(iterable, sentinel):
    return reversed(list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != sentinel, reversed(iterable))))

def dropwhile_v2(iterable, sentinel):
    return list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != sentinel, iterable[::-1]))[::-1]


def dropwhile_jon(iterable, sentinel):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item
        if item == sentinel:
            return

def dropwhile_vivek(iterable, sentinel):
    try:
        target_index = iterable.index(sentinel) + 1
    except ValueError:
        target_index = None

    return iterable[:target_index]

def dropwhile_autonomou(iterable, sentinel):
    if sentinel in iterable:
       slice = [fr for fr in iterable[:fruits.index(sentinel)+1]]
       return slice


from random import uniform
seq = [uniform(1,100) for _ in range(100)]

def test(callable):
    sentinel = uniform(1,100)
    callable(seq, sentinel)
"""

import timeit
for method in ['dropwhile_v1', 'dropwhile_v2', 'dropwhile_vivek', 'dropwhile_jon', 'dropwhile_autonomou']:
    print ('%s: %fs' % (method, timeit.timeit('test(%s)' % method, setup=setup, number=1000000)))
```

Output:

```
dropwhile_v1: 12.979626s
dropwhile_v2: 13.234087s
dropwhile_vivek: 3.883617s
dropwhile_jon: 0.622481s
dropwhile_autonomou: 2.100633s
```

Comment: To correctly test `dropwhile_jon` - you need to materialise to a list so you're comparing apples with apples - otherwise, the test is only initialising the generator function

Comment: Also you have "fruits" in there where it should be "iterable" I think.

Comment: Other than that you should test with the same sentinel for all methods, not with random ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `dropwhile` in `itertools` that you can use to filter the elements coming after your choice and then you can take minus both you will get what you want :

```
from itertools import dropwhile

dictionary = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
filtered = dropwhile(lambda t: 'pear' not in t, dictionary)
next(filtered)
print(list(set(dictionary)-set(list(filtered)))
```

It will o/p like :

```
['apple', 'pear']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'banana']
l1 = [x for x in l1[0:l1.index(<target>)+1]]
```

Abstracting it out to a function, for modularity and re-use would be ideal.

```
>>> li
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'tomato']
>>> 
>>> def slice_and_dice(fruit, fruits):
...    
        if fruit in fruits:
...        slice = [fr for fr in l1[:fruits.index(fruit)+1]]
...        return slice
... 
>>> slice_and_dice('pear', li)
['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
```

Comment: Your [fr for fr in l1[:fruits.index(fruit)+1]] can be shorter written as l1[:fruits.index(fruit)+1]. The list comprehension here has no benefit.

Comment: It might also be shorter if I included the condition within it, the benefit I have for list comprehensions is easier to read, not the same for everyone.

Comment: Ahh, cool, I see what you mean now. I misread what you meant before.

Decided to re-write for fun using your advice http://fpaste.org/181051/14229894/

Answer (score 0):

```
    l1=(["apple","pear","banana"]) 
    del l1[1:]
```

deletes anything beyond the list item 1 (apple is 0)